# Woocomerce buying same product at same time by two customers issue

Tags: ajax, database, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have a little problem.

Case(WooCommerce): Two customers are buying same product at same time, but product quantity only 1. Both of them are available to add product in cart ant then checkout. Both of them are paying in PayPal, but only 1 of them may receive the product, other custom will get Canceled order, buy PayPal still keeps the money. And this is a problem.

Is there a way to avoid this? Maybe someone knows how to reserve product after someone press 'Add to cart', so other customer wont be able to do this in same time?

Thanks You for Ideas!

Comment: a quick solution will be like, check available quantity when someone adds product in cart and if it was last product available, then set a Flag in DB with that Product, which will denied any other customer to buy it until the flag is updated to available.

Comment: Hmm, it might work. Thank!